# System.Timers.Timer Restart without AutoReset ignores Intervall

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, timer, task

I got a System.Timers.Timer (Even if Threading.Timer is more powerfull, I need the restart option) which should call an Event(Function) for data exchange.
My Timer Init:

```
private System.Timers.Timer _scheduler;     //on class level  
_scheduler = new System.Timers.Timer(double.Parse(Config.TimeIntervall));
_scheduler.AutoReset = false;
_scheduler.Elapsed += (o, args) => InterfaceSingleRun();
_scheduler.Start();
```

The function starts a task, and in the `finally` statement I got

```
_scheduler.Start()
```

to restart my Timer, which should start counting down the intervall again

My Problem: I want to prevent overlapping, because I don't know how long the Task will be running (depends on Server), but the `_schedulter.Start()` just restarts the Elapsed Event, instead of waiting the intervall time.
Could you please tell me if I just misunderstood the MSDN-Site/the Timer got some issues and how to fix them/or my code is just messed up :)

Thanks

EDIT:
Solved the Problem, thanks to Hans Passant.
I was working with seconds, which the program interpreted as milliseconds.

Comment: My crystal ball says that `Config.TimeIntervall` is in seconds instead of milliseconds.

Comment: I want your crystal ball....
Indeed, it is. Just can't test it right now because my code doesn't work..
You will get an answer as soon as I fixed some other little problems ;)

Comment: Don't bother, just multiply it by 1000.

Comment: All Hail your crystal ball :)
fixed my code, multiplied by 1000 and everything is fine..
was testing with  - I thought - 20 sec, which were 20 ms and that looks like immediate restart. 
If you get me something to mark as solution, I will do. 
Thanks for fixing

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct, you want to prevent a second trigger while the code inside the timer_tick is running.

i use a global bool like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static bool timercodeRunning;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);

        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!timercodeRunning)
        {
            timercodeRunning = true;
            try
            {
                //DO SOME STUFF


                timercodeRunning = false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                timercodeRunning = false;
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I don't want to loose/ignore the Elapsed-Event, I just want to delay it.
The timer should start again with the full 5000 when the function has finished.
Your example could give the possibility to restart immediately after the function has finished, i.e. when the duration is 9990.

Comment: you could just stop the timer when starting the tick, and start the timer again once your code is finished (or in the catch/finaly)

Answer (score 0):

instead of bool i recommended you to try locking. here is modified code of Gelootn

```
    class Program
{
    private static object timercodeRunning = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);

        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (timercodeRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                //DO SOME STUFF
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```